# Bootstrap-5 css files versus scss files

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I've just started learning a bit about Bootstrap and used npm to install Bootstrap. I noticed under node_modules that there are css files and scss files under Bootstrap. What I know of scss so far is that it's an advanced version of css, so I was wondering what the difference between the css Bootstrap files and the scss Bootstrap files were. Do they contain different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what is ultimately rendered to the browser should be identical out of the box.  The difference is that to serve the SCSS to the browser you have to have some build process in your development workflow that outputs the SCSS to CSS before serving it.  There are, however, some benefits to using [the SCSS files in your project](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass), such as easier customization and access to mixins and helper utilities.